# Float issue with jQuery/javascript and WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, webkit

I'm having a problem related to WebKit:
http://demo.frojd.se/webkit/index.html

When you click "Menu item 1" it shows it's children.
This renders fine in Firefox 3.5, IE8 and in Opera 10.
In WebKit-browsers (Safari 4 and Chrome 3) it doesn't.

However, if I preset all the different classes and css-settings in the
html, it renders correctly (without the javascript click events). I've got an URL to show you, but can't since this is my first post.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Cheers,
Robin.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how it fails on Webkit? Have you checked the JS console?

Comment: Sure thing! It fails in the way that when you click "Menu item 1" in the URL, it expands, but brakes the floats that then is activated (due to new classes introduced by js). 

If you view the same page in FF3, IE8 or Opera10 it doesn't brake.

The JS console shows no errors.

Comment: Here are a screenshot of webkit: http://demo.frojd.se/webkit/webkit.PNG

...and here's one of firefox: 
http://demo.frojd.se/webkit/firefox.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really haven't looked at the code closely, but something to look at in this situation is the padding or margin set on the menu item divs.  In Safari, those are not taken into account with respect to width, so they may make the div or contents of the div expand wider than you expect, and that would cause the next element to be pushed to somewhere you don't expect it.

Not sure if that'll help, but it's some place you can look if you're still stuck.

Edit: After looking at the source using Web Inspector, it seems the divs with class = 'parentHook' are not wide enough after getting clicked on.  After getting clicked on the class changes to 'parentContainer', which sets 'margin-left:-18px; margin-top:-15px;', and that seems to throw off the width of that div.  In Web Inspector I changed the width of that div to 150px, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!
Tested without any added margins or paddings, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Awesome find, this will help me finishing it! So it seems that WebKit needs a fixed width for this to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A true and ugly hack- but hey it works.
try hiding and showing on the click of the  `<li>`

for a simple test: try this in console

```
$('#nav li:first').hide(50).show(50)
```

Comment: Hi :) ! I tried to do this, but without results. What was the idea? Do you think that the <a> triggers a different response with WebKit browsers than a <li> would do?